# Uploading / Simulating a Collection of Songs on the Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, emulation, zune

I am writing a windows phone 7 game that deals with extracting the spectrum out of a song and building the game level based on that. The only problem I have so far, though is that I cannot use any song out of the Zune media library, because there aren't any on the emulator. I do not have a device yet. I downloaded an unlocked build of the emulator, which has more apps, including zune, but when I open Zune, it seems to be empty.

Can I somehow upload or simulate (add songs to the medialibrary at runtime) a song collection so that I can test the game with the emulator?

P.S. I think that there's a tool that let's you sync your device to the Zune client on the PC, but I'm not sure whether it will work with the emulator.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't sync between your PC and the emulator.

I, however see 3 songs available in the emulator by default though.
You can access them via the [MediaLibrary.Songs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.songs.aspx) collection. Simply add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` (Yes, even if you've got a Silverlight based project.) and you're good to go.

```
using (var myMediaLibrary = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach (var song in myMediaLibrary.Songs)
    {
        songList.Items.Add(new TextBlock {Text = song.Name});
    }
}
```

You must have the RTM version of the tools though as they weren't there in the Beta or CTP versions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it out in a minute, and will make sure to write feedback afterwards

Comment: That was it. I installed the RTM from scratch, and was able to access the MediaLibrary. Thanks